# Using AJAX to update data in Django templates

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-templates

I have a simple messaging system built. I want to update the inbox div whenever there is a new message.

html:

```
<div id="inbox">
            <h6>Inbox</h6>
            {% for message in inbox %}
                <ul>
                    <li title="{{ message.sender.username }}">{{ message.sender.first_name }}: {{ message.msg_content }}
                        <button onclick="myFunction()">Reply</button>
                    </li>
                    <small>-{{ message.timestamp }}</small>
                    <hr>
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

Views:

```
def user_messages(request):
    time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
    user = request.user

    if request.method == "POST":
        sender = request.user
        receiver_name = request.POST.get('msg_receiver')
        receiver = User.objects.get(username=receiver_name)
        msg_content = request.POST.get('msg_content')

        Messages.objects.create(sender=sender, receiver=receiver, msg_content=msg_content)

    inbox = Messages.objects.filter(receiver=user).order_by('-timestamp')
    outbox = Messages.objects.filter(sender=user).order_by('-timestamp')

    context = {'inbox': inbox, 'outbox': outbox, 'time_now': time_now}

    return render(request, 'accounts/messages.html', context)
```

Whenever there is a new message in inbox, i.e inbox length is greater I want the div (id=inbox) to update.

I added a script in the html file:

```
$('.inbox').click(function () {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "{% url 'messages' %}",
                    data: {
                        
                    },
                })
        });
```

How do I check changes in the objects model?

Comment: You could fire the AJAX request every X second using a `set_delay` and check if a new object was populated to the database by storing the number of last objects sum in the template as parameter and pass this via AJAX to compare it against the object numbers in the db query

Comment: Do you know if that is how twitter updates share counts or are they using websockets?